# How does a Discord Bot that is added to someone else's server get the channel id of where they want it to send messages?

Tags: python, discord.py

I currently have a discord bot that works well on my own private server. I would like the bot to have the ability to join other people's servers if they choose to add them, but one of the parts of my bot is that it automatically sends messages to a specific channel every so often. To do this, I used the channel id of the channel that I use on my server:

```
async def esportsdiscussions():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel([Channel Id])
    await channel.send('Hi!')
```

If my bot was added to another server my server's channel id obviously wouldn't work so is there a way to automatically get the general channel id from a server that it's on? Or is there another way to create a list of channel ids for different servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `on_guild_join` event to get the guild with all his channels
or also find the guild, by id or name, and then find a channel by id or name

But if you want to keep the channel ids stored, even after restart you need to save them to a database or something like that
You can either use MongoDB (as I do), or if it is just a smaler projekt JSON, SQLite, or just a .txt would also work

I will use a python dict as example, which is pretty similar to JSON or the MongoDB output

```py
database = {      # if this is in a .json file, only use everyting 
    "guilds": [   # behind "database = ", starting with the first { and the last }
        {
            "guild_id": 1111,     # you can already set this to your guild 
            "channel_id": 1112    # and channel id
        }
    ]
}


@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    """
        You can try to find a channel with a specific name here and use this,
        but maybe the name does not exists, so i don't recommend this
    """
    # for example
    for channel in guild.text_channels:  
        if channel.name == "something":
            ...


@bot.command()
async def set_channel(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    """You can use a command so server admins kann set the channel by themself"""

    current_guild_ids = [guild["guild_id"] for guild in database["guild"]]
    if ctx.guild.id in current_guild_ids:  # check if the guild already exists in the db
        await ctx.send("You already set a channel")
    else:  # add the guild and channel to the db
        new_guild_data = {"guild_id": ctx.guild.id, "channel_id": channel.id}
        database["guilds"].append(new_guild_data)
        await ctx.send("Channel was added")


# and if you want to get the guild without a event or command you can do this:

async def some_function():
    guild_data = database["guilds"][0]  # the first guild in the db for example
    # prints: {"guild_id": 1111, "channel_id": 1112}
    guild = bot.get_guild(guild_data["guild_id"])
    channel = bot.get_channel(guild_data["channel_id"])
    # then you can send messages to it
    await channel.send("Hi!")


    # or find the by name with discord.utils.find()
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.name == 'GuildName', client.guilds)
    channel = discord.utils.find(lambda c: c.name == 'ChannelName', guild.channels)
```

[`discord.utils.find`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.utils.find) docs

Comment: Thank you so much for this response! I really appreciate how well throughout and detailed everything is! I will try a few things from this stuff and see how I want to set it up but I was mainly thinking about using a command to set the channel id. If you were to choose one way to implement this, which one do you think you would use?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every server your bot joins would have `#general`, the simplest way would be to use [`discord.utils`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#utility-functions)' get function. It would iterate through the guild's channels, and return a channel object if a `#general` channel is found.

```py
channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name="general")
```

Other questions like this:

- [Is it possible to get channel ID by name in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63321098/is-it-possible-to-get-channel-id-by-name-in-discord-py)
- [get the name of a channel using discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52916317/get-the-name-of-a-channel-using-discord-py)
- [Send a message when the bot joins a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48834656/send-a-message-when-the-bot-joins-a-server) (a bit old, would need tweaking)

---

Sometimes, a server may have their general labeled as `#╚general`, `#general`, etc, which would be able to bypass the above code. You could use this slightly longer method in this case.

```py
for channel in ctx.guild.channels: # for every channel in this guild,
    if "general" in channel.name.lower() # if the word 'general' is in this channel's name (lowercase)
        channel = channel # the channel variable is now this channel
        break # stop the loop
```

Overall, the only main issue would be if the guild does not have a `#general` of any sort, such as a change of font or not having the channel to begin with.

Answer (score -1):

```
for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
    print(channel.id)
```

this code will list all the channel in that server.
if you want the name use `channel.name`

or you can use `bot.get_all_channels()` which will return all the channels in list

Comment: Wouldn't this need to be used within a command function for the ctx.guilds to work? Is there a different way to get it without having to call a function?

Comment: if you use `bot = discord.commands.Bot()` you can access to the `bot.get_all_channels()` anywhere